# Out of Stock Configurable Products in list.phtml

Tags: configurable-product, out-of-stock, list.phtml

I need to display a "sold out" text to all products in a list.phtml file...

I'm using `<?php if($_product->isSaleable()) : ?>` and it's working great for simple products but it's not working for configurable.

I've tried few things, and for example this code

```
    if($productType == "configurable") {
        $arrayvalori = array("Small"=>"0","Regular"=>"0","Large"=>"0");
        $attValConfig = $product->getTypeInstance()->getConfigurableAttributesAsArray();

        if(sizeof($attValConfig)) {
            $hasAtts++;
            foreach($attValConfig as $attValConfigSingle) {
                foreach($attValConfigSingle['values'] as $attValConfigSingleVal) {
                    if($arrayvalori[$attValConfigSingleVal["label"]] > 0) {
                            echo 'buy';
                    } else {
                        echo "sold out";
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

it works but returns all of the available attributes statuses (for the given configurable product)
output example:

```
buy
buy
buy
buy
sold out
sold out
buy
```

I want it to display buy if 1 or more variations are available and display sold out if all are sold out?!?!!

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer is already in your question. As you said it is showing buy and sold out correctly after loop. You will just need to modify your code little bit.

```
$canBuy = false;
foreach ($attValConfig as $attValConfigSingle) {
    foreach ($attValConfigSingle['values'] as $attValConfigSingleVal) {
        if ($arrayvalori[$attValConfigSingleVal["label"]] > 0) {
            $canBuy = true;
        } 
    }
}

if($canBuy){
    echo 'buy';
}
else {
    echo 'sold out';
}
```

Comment: thanks for replay.. but now it's showing only sold out

Comment: can you post your list.phtml file code here?

Comment: here's it is http://pastebin.com/JeRkwLs5

Comment: the part I'm working on starts on line 386

Comment: I think this is your original code. how did you tried with my trick? Can you post that?

Comment: here it's. line 386 > http://pastebin.com/ErVjjVKr

Comment: It looks ok. but not sure why it is not working. can you try to log or echo something after $canBuy = true;. so you can get how many times it is coming in that loop.

Comment: I tried again and it's working right now! Thank you  Akhilesh for the help, really appreciate

Comment: Great, glad to hear that :)